# Not possible to Reload code in Android emulator (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

I have modified `build.gradle` in the project, after the finishing modifying it, it's not possible to reload code in the Android emulator using R-R or using cmd+M. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: di you launch it from Android Studio or terminal?

Comment: @Ilario terminal

Comment: When you write: react-native run-android the packager start?

Comment: @Ilario yes, it starts, it's working, all app is working as usually, but it's not possible to reload code using R-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
Clean project => Build => Edit Build Type => select Your Modules (app) => tab build Type => change Debugable to true
```

Sync and build again!
Now reloading using R-R working again!